# How to associate distant tokens in ANTLER

Tags: antlr4

Suppose I have the text "1,2,3:A,B,C". I would like to build an ANTLR4 grammar that produces a token that associates 1 with A, 2 with B and 3 with C for the above example. I know we can use pushmodes but this seems to use FILO, I need something that can do FIFO.

I will then use this token in Java to  create an object.

Comment: Have you already tried something? If so, could you include that in your question please?

Comment: Parse two lists of tokens separated by the `:`. Use tree visitor or tree listener to associate the n-th item of the first list with the corresponding second.

Comment: A token has a type and a value, and a token stream is an ordered list of tokens. You should not be creating one token for both '1' and 'A'. It makes no sense from both theory and practice of what lexers do. In Antlr, a CommonToken retains the start and stop index in the input char buffer, so '1' and 'A' are different tokens. If you want to associate the token for string '1' and the token for string 'A', create a mapping from Token to Token with a parse tree traversal as mentioned above.